# Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types web3 python

Tags: ether, web3.py, python, goerli

I am trying to access smart contract but its returns
Could not identify the intended function with name `createEscrowOrder`, positional arguments with type(s) `int,address,float` and keyword arguments with type(s) `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `createEscrowOrder`: ['createEscrowOrder(uint256,address,uint256)']
Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types

```
from web3 import Web3

# Connect to an Ethereum node
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://goerli.infura.io/v3/#'))
contract_address = '0x446#'  # Address of your smart contract
contract_abi = [{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"arbiter","outputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"orderId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"confirmDelivery","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"orderId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"confirmPayment","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"orderId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address payable","name":"_seller","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_usdtAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"createEscrowOrder","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"escrowOrders","outputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"buyer","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address payable","name":"seller","type":"address"},{"internalType":"enum Escrow.State","name":"state","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"usdtAmount","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"numberOfOrders","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"orderId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"returnPayment","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"revenue","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"usdtContractAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]        # ABI of your smart contract

contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi)
user_address='0x08#'



function_name = 'createEscrowOrder'
function_result = contract.functions[function_name](123,contract_address,.001).call()
```

Comment: You are passing a float for the last value. It cannot encode the float as a uint256.
Use a value between 0 and max uint256. No decimal places.

Comment: its my amount. And can i convert it to uint256 bymyself?

Comment: Yes you need to convert the number first. If a token amount, multiply by 10 to the power of, the number of decimals the token has. so 0.003 weth would become:
(0.003 * (10 ^ 18)) = 3000000000000000
You will never be passing floats to a smart contract.